# How to set transparency for pictures loaded with CImage?

Tags: mfc, png, transparency, gdi+

I use CImage to load `.png` files and use `Draw` to draw them on the screen. Now I'd like to set the transparency when drawing some pictures, but after looking up in MSDN, I find that there isn't anything like `SetAlpha()` or any overrides of `Draw` which allows me to determine the transparency.

Is there any way or workaround to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [CImage::AlphaBlend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2zk0d0f.aspx) or [CImage::TransparentBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h3tedyw.aspx). 
These seem to be the "overrides of Draw" you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing me with the information and terribly sorry for the delay. AlphaBlend is exactly what fulfills my requirement, it can control the transparency with a parameter.